# Check Multiple Contains() and store the value dynamically

Tags: c#

I have a string function in which i have to check multiple characters. My code is

```
if(str.Contains("R") || str.Contains("f") || str.Contains("W") )
{
         string letter= "";

}
```

My question is if string contains R then it has to be stored in letter variable, if f contains it has to be stored. How can I achieve it by not using multiple if conditions??

Comment: And what if the string contains all the letters searched?

Comment: What you are doing is OK..I think this is the best option in your case!

Comment: no... only one letter will be there

Comment: So no ifs. Is a `switch-case statement` allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want something like this?

```
string str = "abcRefg";
var letters = new[] { "R", "f", "W" };

string foundLetter = null;
foreach (var letter in letters)
{
    if (str.Contains(letter))
    {
        foundLetter = letter;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add `break;` after first found.

Comment: Very true. Edited my answer.

Comment: This code doesn't compile at all. I am a bit astonished how it is possible that it _works fine_.

Comment: Woops. Fixed foundLetter's type, also added OP's str variable. Thanks.

Comment: No way still broken. Please test it adding a Console.WriteLine(foundLetter) after the loop

Comment: string str = "123'R'";
            string[] letters =new string[] { "R", "w","f"};

            
            foreach (var letter in letters)
            {
                if (str.Contains(letter))
                {
                    string x = letter;
                    Console.WriteLine(x);
                }
               
            }

Comment: @DamenEU in the usage shown by the OP there is no error because he declared the variable inside the loop and it seems that all the work on that letter is done inside the loop, but in your answer the declaration of foundletter and the break seems to indicate that you want to use the foundletter outside the loop. In this case the compiler doesn't allow to use the foundletter variable because it thinks that it is uninitialized (As said try with a Console.WriteLine outside the loop)

Comment: Now it's fine, still... oh well if the OP is good with this. See you again on SO.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [string.IndexOfAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to find the position of one of the letters

```
int pos = str.IndexOfAny(new char[] {'R','f','W'});
if(pos >= 0)
{
    string letter = str[pos].ToString();
    ....
}
```

Comment: no need to find position. I just want that character to be stored in that letter variable

Comment: but he has to use the position to get the letter

Comment: Finding the position is the first step to extract the letter (if any exists). No complex if required, and, if you have more letters to search, just add them to the char array.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to know *which* characters `str` contains, you can use the [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb460136.aspx) extension method.

```
char[] characters = {'R', 'f', 'W'};
var common = str.Intersect(characters).ToList();

foreach(char c in common)
{ 

}
```